# Wordpress query that sorts by category and time

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I have found this question:

[Wordpress outside loop sort by category and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847383/wordpress-outside-loop-sort-by-category-and-time)

But there is not a lot of context provided in the question or answer to know if it is applicable to me. I am using the popular genesis framework and a child theme. I don't want to modify any core WP files because they would be overwritten on updates. I think this can be done through my functions.php or front-page.php file.

I have 25 posts listed at a time. Within those 25 posts, I would like to have any post that is from category one be listed on top and those from category two listed afterwards. Within the category one and category two loops, the posts would be listed by time of entry as normal.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to sort the whole result, but only within the current search result page? That sounds like it might confuse people.

Comment: This is just a visit to the front page and then when they occasionally click on "page 2", etc... My readers get angry when the category 2 posts are listed before the category 1 posts and it would be a pain to manually adjust this every day, since we post 10-45 times a day. It would be much easier to just sort them in two categories and let people look through category one and then if they have time category two. Some days there will not be any category two posts in the top 25. That's ok. Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 0):

SDS
You need two loop one for categories and one for posts.
So you can try this type of code

```
/*category args for listed according to name in assending order*/
$category_arg = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );

$all_cat = get_categories($category_arg);

/*Loop for all category*/
foreach ($all_cat as $key => $cat) {

/*Query for post of perticular category with orderby posted date*/  
$args =  array(
    'cat'  => $cat->cat_ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
) ;

query_posts( $args );

echo '
<div class="one-category-block">
    <h1>'.$cat->cat_name.'</h1>';
echo '<ul>';
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
                the_title();
    echo '</li>

';
endwhile;
echo '</ul>
</div>';


wp_reset_query();


}
```

Try this type of code , then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use query_posts https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Answer (score 0):

All right. You won't be able to do that on the query directly, I'm afraid.

However, it's still easy to do. First, get the posts out of the query into an array:

```
$posts = array();
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    array_push($posts, $post);
}
```

Then sort that array:

```
usort($posts, function($a, $b) {
    if(has_term("mycategory", "mytaxonomy", $a->ID) && !has_term("mycategory", "mytaxonomy", $b->ID))  return -1;
    if(!has_term("mycategory", "mytaxonomy", $a->ID) && has_term("mycategory", "mytaxonomy", $b->ID))  return 1;
    return $b->post_date - $a->post_date;
});
```

I've made it so that posts having `mycatgegory` in the `mytaxonomy` taxonomy will be on top, but generally sorted by post date.

Then just use a regular foreach loop to iterate over  the (now sorted) posts

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    // continue outputting the posts here
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

`setup_postdata()` is there to make sure that you can use get_the_ID(), get_permalink() et cetera without changing your code.